solving a 4th degree equation using the Ferrari method
$x^4+4ix^3+(-8+(1+4i)\sqrt3) x^2 + (4-2i-(4-8i)\sqrt3) x - 9/4 + 10i-(4-4i)\sqrt3=0$
It's my equation i used replacement $x \rightarrow x-i$ to bring to canonical form.
I found resolvent of canonical form and i got:
$2s^3-((1+4i)\sqrt3-2)s^2-2s((3+4i)\sqrt3+3/4+6i)+((1+4i)\sqrt3-2)((3+4i)\sqrt3+3/4+6i) - ((6i+4)+\sqrt3(6i+4))/4=0$
I found roots of resolvent and there are:
$x_{1,2}= -\sqrt3/2+(-1\pm 2i)$ 
$x_{3} = 1 + (3/2+2i)\sqrt3$
But i tried to follow guides in internet but roots which i found but they do not correspond to the answer that tungsten gives.
In general, I find the roots of the resolvent, but I don’t understand what to do next with them, the roots of the resolvent turned out to be quite beautiful, but following the guides from the Internet, my answer does not agree with tungsten, tell me how to solve, thanks for your attention

What you are calling “canonical form” is usually called “reduced form”. Anyway, which concept of resolvent cubic are you using? It doesn't seem to be any of these.

Here's the solution from Mathematica:
$$x = \frac{1}{2} \left((2-i)-(2+i) \sqrt{3}\right)\
x= \frac{1}{2} i \left((-5-2 i)-(1+2 i) \sqrt{3}\right)\
x= \frac{1}{2} i \left(\sqrt{3}+(-3+4 i)\right)\
x= \frac{1}{2} i \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$$ Is that the same you found?

The equation can be factored to two quadratics

I know the solution but i can't factorized that.
I used this resolvent:
x^3-2((1+4i)sqrt(3)-2)x^2+(((1+4i)sqrt(3)-2)^2 - 4((3+4i)sqrt(3) +3/4+6i))*x+((4+6i)sqrt(3)+(4+6i))^2=0
(its R_3 from the wiki)
I found roots and what next step tell please

That is not the resolvent cubic mentioned at the post. So, which one did you really use?
